# IO.readlines method in ruby behaving wierdly?

Tags: ruby, io

It sounds stupid but it has given me 3 hr of head banging...!!
I have created a class method in which I am extracting a file base name (placed in the Root folder). The issue is IO.readlines method is not accepting the file with a base name returned from the fetching. It returns error:

```
./lib/fileCheck.rb:36:in `readlines': No such file or directory -  (Errno::ENOENT)
```

But it works as soon as I manually enter the file base name in readlines. Here is the class method:

```
class FileCheck
  def self.read_file
    file = File.basename(Dir[File.join(File.expand_path('../.'), "*.txt")].to_s)
    file = IO.readlines(file)
    return file
  end
end
```

No result, but as soon as I place the file name manually, it works perfectly.

```
  def self.read_file
  #file = File.basename(Dir[File.join(File.expand_path('../.'), "*.txt")].to_s)
  file = IO.readlines('sample.txt')
  return file
 end
```

I check with irb and the statement

```
File.basename(Dir[File.join(File.expand_path('../.'), "*.txt")].to_s)
```

is returning a file base name of class String.

Any suggestions?????

Comment: What exactly does that `basename` call return? Post result of `p file_fasta`

Comment: in irb it returns a file basename (e.g 'sample.txt') of class string. and this is what I want. During prog execution also the basename returned file variable is of class string. But somehow its not working with readlines???

Comment: ohh p file_fasta returns nothing?? an empty string

Comment: What do you expect `File.basename(Dir[File.join(File.expand_path('../.'), "*.txt")].to_s)` to return?

Comment: Sergio, thanx for replying but I resolved the issue. The issue was in expand path. Now its working ok.

Comment: Stefan, sorry but I modified the File.expand_path('../.') to File.expand_path(APP_ROOT). Now its working fine. APP_ROOT is the location from where I initialize the prog. The file which I am going to read is also in APP_ROOT. Now its working as expected. Thanx

Answer (score 1):

it does not matter if you use `expand_path` or `join`. you still have a mayor issue in your code:

```
File.basename(Dir[File.join(File.expand_path('../.'), "*.txt")].to_s)
```

the `Dir[]` also known as `Dir.glob` returns an array! make sure to pick one of the elements instead of calling `to_s`. you will run into problems when there is more than one file.

Comment: Thanx for pointing this out phoet. It will return issues with multiple files. I just wanted to pick up a file, based on file extension, from different location. Is there any way I can avoid using Dir[]??

Comment: to be honest, i did not understand why you are using this. is the filename unknown and you just know about the extension? if that is the case, you will have to iterate over the results of Dir[]

Comment: in this case I did not want user to specify the file, instead, I wanted the prog detects the file based on the extension making it more user friendly. There would be only one file with a particular extension.